# Redirect page in Spring Boot with Jpa and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf, one-to-many

I am creating a one to many relationship, where Category has many Products. After listingn all my existing categories,I want to see all the products in a specifc category and to do basic CRUD on those products(from that category).
I find dificulties in redirecting pages in Thymealeaf, most exactly I can't acces the "Add Product" page, using Thymeleaf.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Product> products;

    public Category(){}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private float price;

    @Column
    private int discount;

    @Column
    private boolean isInStock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;
```

Here is my my way of saving products in Service layer

```
 public Product save(Product product, long id) {
        Category category = categoryRepository.getById(id);
        if (category != null) {
            product.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            product.setCategory(category);
            product.setInStock(false);
            return productRepository.save(product);
        } else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Category not found with id: " + id);
        }
    }
```

In controller I have:

```
@Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/products/{categoryId}")
    public String viewProducts(Model model, @PathVariable("categoryId") long categoryId) {
        List<Product> productsList = productService.findByCategoryId(categoryId);
        model.addAttribute("productsList", productsList);
        model.addAttribute("categoryId",categoryId );
        return "products";

    }
    @GetMapping("/newProduct/{categoryId}")
    public String showAddForm(Model model,@PathVariable("categoryId") long categoryId) {
        Product product = new Product();
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        return "newProduct";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save/{categoryId}")
    public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, @PathVariable long categoryId){
        productService.save(product, categoryId);
        return "redirect:products";
    }
```

Where I am stuck is that I can't redirect from products.html to newProduct.html (that showAddForm method should return) using the path variable categoryId.It redirects me to an error page where if I enter the categoryId by hand in the URL,I finally get to the newProduct.html. In the products.html, I have:

```
<body>
<div class="container my-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
       <!-- TODO get category ID from categories  (parameters between HTML)-->
            <div th:switch="${productsList}" class="container my-5">

                <p class="my-5">
                    <a href="/product/newProduct/" class="btn btn-primary">Add product</a>
                </p>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h2 th:case="null">No Products yet!</h2>
                    <div th:case="*">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Discount</th>
                                <th>IsInStock</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="product : ${productsList}">
                                <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${product.discount}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${product.isInStock}"></td>
                                <td><a th:href="@{/product/edit/{id}(id=${product.id})}" class="btn btn-primary"></a></td>
                                <td><a th:href="@{/product/delete/{id}(id=${product.id})}" class="btn btn-primary"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is, your code for `showAddForm` with the path `@GetMapping("/newProduct/{categoryId}")` is expecting a catgoryID which is not sent in the above Add product button. Since you are passing a categoryId in the line `model.addAttribute("categoryId",categoryId );` you can use this in the href element. Therefore, that link should be something like

```
<p class="my-5">
    <a th:href="@{/product/newProduct(categoryId=${categoryId})}" class="btn btn-primary">Add product</a>
</p>
```

But since within the method `showAddForm` categoryID is not used, so you can remove that. And try with something like

```
<p class="my-5">
    <a th:href="@{/product/newProduct}" class="btn btn-primary">Add product</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Basically passing the category Id itself to the html is my problem so as to get to use your proposed soloution, cause I guess I have to bring a Category object into an html we're i'm working only with Product object. Sorry for the silly question, it is just my first time i try to use thymeleaf and I am building my own version on examples already found on the internet.

Comment: @AlexandraDediu You are actually passing the `categoryId` in the `viewProducts` method. I did not see that.  I have edited my answer.This solution should work. Let me know